# Custom Help Page on Azure Mobile Services?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to make a clean & nice Documentation of my Azure mobile service, though the auto-generated help pages donot include the 
/// comment information

I tried to import the Help page package from Nu-get but when i deploy they dont seem to work.

Google search failed. 
Is there any link to Azure Mobile Services Custom Help Page Tutorial ? 
Or 
Has anyone achieved to show the /// comments on the auto-generated help page?

Comment: Perhaps DocumentX is something that you would like to have a look at? We use it for documentation generation for services as well as libraries. The nice part is that is can combine 'generated' documentation (from comments) with manually entered documentation.

Comment: Tried it out. Its too complicated and the produced docs are too unfriendly for a mobile service WebAPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When create an Azure Mobile Service and deploy it to the server or run it in localhost, we can see the API Documentation as following

[image]

and

[image]

which is decrived in this article

[microsoft’s windows app studio beta: connecting a menu app to azure mobile service > Running the Services](http://www.saramgsilva.com/index.php/2014/microsoft-windows-app-studio-beta-connecting-a-menu-app-to-azure-mobile-service/)

But if you comment each service as following

```
    // GET tables/Customer
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all customer dto.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>IQueryable&lt;CustomerDto&gt;.</returns>
    public IQueryable<CustomerDto> GetAllCustomerDto()
    {
        try
        {
            return Query();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException entityValidationException)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(entityValidationException.GetDetails());
            throw;
        }

    }
```

These comments are not loaded in the API Documentation. And the only thing I see here is to generate the xml files with the comments (like we do [to create APIs documentations like MSDN](http://www.saramgsilva.com/index.php/2014/creating-framework-documentation-with-ghostdoc/)) and load it in the web page generate to the API Documentation, because API documentation do not do it by default and I have doubts if is possible

Comment: Don't really get your answer. I talk specifically about mobile services.. They generate some docs by default.

Comment: I edited it to try to be more clear, I hope we are talking about the same thing.

Comment: I see so actually its not possible to change the default docs. 
I ll take a look at GhostDoc. Had seen it before posting the question but was hoping for an easier solution.
Thx anyway :)

Comment: glad to know, that now it is more clear to you... :)